# Multiple auth for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to split middleware auth to two role one is for admin and second for user 
but some route is use for all user and admin and few route is for admin only how can i split with route?

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {        
     //Some route here 
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
   //some route here
});
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#controller-middleware

Check the only method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my implementation for access control for admin and users(agents in my case) I have a boolean field in my user table (`is_admin`) which is 0 for normal users and 1 for admins.

**In your User model add this:**

```
protected $casts = [
    'is_admin' => 'boolean',
];

public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->is_admin;
}
```

**Create a new middlewares for Admin and Agent:**

```
php artisan make:middleware Admin

php artisan make:middleware Agent
```

The middleware files will be created in `App\Http\Middleware\`

**Add this to class inside `Admin.php`:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/agent');
}
```

**Add this to `Agent.php`**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{    
    if ( Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
    {
        return $next($request);
    }    
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

After this **register your middleware** with laravel to do this add this to `protected $routeMiddleware` in your `Kernel.php` which is located at `app\Http\Kernel.php`

```
'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',
'agent' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Agent',
```

Make sure to create proper routes for redirection as we've mentioned in our middleware files. After this you are almost done. Now to verify if a user is admin or normal user add this to the constructor method of your controller.

**Actions allowed only for admin users:**

```
    public function __construct()
{   

    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

**Action allowed only for normal (agent) users:**

```
public function __construct() {

$this->middleware('auth');
$this->middleware('agent');

}
```

**Or you can also add middleware to your routes,**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {        
     //Some route here 
});
```